# RecyclerView Not Showing Data Passed From List Through Bundle

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in a dialog fragment, which hosts a tab layout, containing a list of checkable items and a button each. When an item is selected, it is passed on click through the bundle to this parent dialog fragment like this:

```
doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retrieveSessions();
        }
    });

private void retrieveSessions() {
    NewProgramDialog dialog = new NewProgramDialog(); // parent dialog fragment is passed the list items here

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String s = new Gson().toJson(myItemsList);
    bundle.putString(KEY_MY_SESSIONS, s);
    bundle.putBoolean("from_selections", true);

    dialog.setArguments(bundle);
    dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "NewProgramDialog");
    dismiss();
}
```

The data for recyclerview is received through a bundle lie shown above and the list items are retrieved using `Gson` and converted to type String, a query is run on the database to get the session model class info. 
These sessions are added to the adapter arraylist like below:

```
private void populateSessions() {

    addProgramSessionsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    addProgramSessionsRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

    // TODO: 2/05/2019 show the added sessions here

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String s = bundle.getString(KEY_MY_SESSIONS); / getting the items from bundle
        myItemsList = new Gson().fromJson(s, ArrayList.class); // parsing to List<String> type
        Log.d(TAG, "Items size:\t" + myItemsList.size()); //works
    }

    adapter = new AddProgramSessionsAdapter(getActivity(), sessionsList);
    addProgramSessionsRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "Items in adapter:\t" + adapter.getItemCount()); // shows total items received from bundle

    for (String s : myItemsList){
        Log.d(TAG, "Ids:\t" + s);

        Sessions session = SQLite.select()
                .from(Sessions.class)
                .where(Sessions_Table.prog_sessionId.eq(s))
                .querySingle();

        sessionsList.add(session);
        Log.d(TAG, "Session List Size:\t" + sessionsList.size());

        adapter = new AddProgramSessionsAdapter(getActivity(), sessionsList);
       addProgramSessionsRV.setAdapter(adapter);
       Log.d(TAG, "Items in adapter:\t" + adapter.getItemCount());

    }

}
```

Still the ui shows no items from this method. I have added the data manually using this snippet and it shows `Session 1` item in view but not the data from db in for loop.
Test Case:

```
    Sessions sessions = new Sessions();
    sessions.setSession_name("Test one");
    sessions.setProgram_id("234");
    sessions.setProg_sessionId("91");
    sessionsList.add(sessions);

    adapter = new AddProgramSessionsAdapter(getActivity(), sessionsList);
    addProgramSessionsRV.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "Items in adapter:\t" + adapter.getItemCount());
```

Is there any reason why setting the adapter to a list which has items does not work in the for loop db query (works)? Please explain to me why the ui shows nothing. Thanks.

Here's the adapter code:

```
public class AddProgramSessionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddProgramSessionViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private List<Sessions> itemsList;

public AddProgramSessionsAdapter(Context context, List<Sessions> itemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

@Override
public AddProgramSessionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_program_sessions_items_layout, parent, false);
    return new AddProgramSessionViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AddProgramSessionViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    Sessions sessions = itemsList.get(position);

    viewholder.add_program_sessionNameTV.setText(sessions.session_name);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(R.drawable.app_logo_resized)
            .into(viewholder.add_program_sessionIV);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (itemsList == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return itemsList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `AddProgramSessionsAdapter`. The problem is probably from there.

Comment: The adapter works with manual data. See the last snippet. Posting it will lengthen the question. Thanks